# Move partitions on disk

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr

In order to install btrfs on my computer, I need a 1mb+ space before the first partition. The First Partition is the boot partition which starts at sector 63, the second partition is the dell recovery partition, the third is the windows partition (fourth is extended partition with linux and swap). Can I move the location of the windows boot partition safely and how? I can delete the dell recovery partition since I don't need it

Comment: So you want to shrink the Windows partition then move it towards the end of the disk along with the boot and the Dell recovery partitions? You do realize that you won't be able to add another partition at the beginning of the disk, right?

Answer (score 0):

Before performing this task, it's highly recommended that you backup your data.

You cannot resize the partition under the Operating System working/running from the same partition.

Boot with Live CD of any linux OSm such as Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian and others, and run [**Gparted**](http://gparted.org/). Or even boot with [Gparted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

As Gparted moves partitions, not unallocated space, it is may be quite complicated task to get your aim. This is because you have a number of partitions.

Moving partitions is a copying itself, so it is going to take many hours. So probably it would be easier to save all critical data as backup to external drive, and then delete all partitions, (re)design a new partitioning, reinstall OS and restore your data from backup.

However if you are still thinking about moving partitions, then yes, it is needed to shrink Windows partition and then move all partitions from left to right.

Comment: *Boot with Live CD of Ubuntu*. I think this is somewhat misleading, of course it's not in the scope of the queston but for the record: almost any linux live image that is debian or redhat based (for example) can run gparted, not just Ubuntu. Even gparted has its own standalone live image.

Comment: @arielnmz I agree with your comment, so I added this to the answer. The better answer the better it may help people.

Comment: Great, sorry if that sounded rude by the way, it's just that I find a little upsetting that some people generalize Linux as Ubuntu. But anyway, +1 for the solid answer.